# Confusion Understanding the mathematical expression of duality property of dft?

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis, fourier-transform, dft, math

[Duality Property for DFT](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/68215/duality-property-for-dft)

Above dsp.se question provides good understanding about dft duality property but i am having difficulty understanding its mathematical expression because on Google when i try to search the topic, i get expression that is bit different from the one in answer of above linked question, so which formula/expression is actually correct??

Expression/formula in answer of above linked question is

Nx(N-k) mod N

[And the one i found on Google.](https://www.google.com/search?q=dft%20duality%20property&client=ms-android-oppo-rev1&prmd=inv&sxsrf=APq-WBv6oR-_tXGOo7VV5Ybkfn50_Cx_WQ:1650791983319&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwji5I2ur6z3AhXCMewKHRB0DWUQ_AUoAXoECAIQAQ&biw=360&bih=648&dpr=2#imgrc=oY5uTxdX3ywGuM)

Is

Nx[((-k))N]

In answer of above linked question,
i understood the left most N is for scaling but i am not able to understand the remaining expression properly, what is meant by that remaining expression? Is it meaning circular shift or linear shift or something else?

If possible, please try to explain your answer by relating to some MATLAB example code for better understanding

Comment: They are equivalent due to periodic. $x[(-k)_N] = x[rN-k]$ where $r\in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Is there any difference between x[(-k)N]  and x[((-k))N] ?? Use of double bracket around -k? If they both are different, please explain

Comment: I think we are talking about the same thing - a periodic signal that repeats every $N$ sample.